# How to set the filename, but the file extension while uploading files in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

`$config['file_name']` allows us to set the filename, while uploading files in CodeIgniter. Here we need to write the filename with the file extension. For example, `filename.pdf` or `filename.zip`. I want to set the filename, but the extension. So, if someone uploads a pdf file, the filename will be `myfilename.pdf`. And if someone uploads a zip file, the filename will be `myfilename.zip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start off the upload stuff in your controller like this and you can name it whatever you want.  just replace 'new_file_name' with whatever you want it to be called.  Make sure you change the do_upload() function variable to the name of your file input as well.

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload('your_filename')) {
            $img_data=$this->upload->data();
            $new_imgname='new_file_name'.$img_data['file_ext'];
            $new_imgpath=$img_data['file_path'].$new_imgname;
            rename($img_data['full_path'], $new_imgpath);
```

Comment: images will most likely still parse correctly in a browser but if you did a pdf to zip if would not work the same unless you converted ext back

Comment: oh ya.  DOn't misinterpret the variable names I'm using up there.  I just pulled some code I use for this that happens to be for image file uploading.  You can rename any file type with this.  I think he just wants to change the files name when he uploads it to the server and keep the extension but I could be wrong.

Comment: To rename filenames is the solution I had in my mind. Thank you for validating it.